# No sound in android emulator which is launched from snap shot

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am having two android emulators. Let's say emulator1 and emulator2. Both these emulators are of Google API 2.1 updated. Emulator1 is always launched after wiping the previous user data. But emulator2 is launched from snapshot (i have taken the snapshot when i have first created emulator2 and using the same snapshot always).
The problem is that i am running an application which can play audio in both emulators. In both emulators audio is playing (i can see it from progress bar), but the sound is only coming from emulator1. In emulator2, progress bar is moving but no sound is coming. 
I have created many emulators like emulator2 (which launches from snapshots) but in none sound is coming. But when i use a fresh emulator like emulator1 sound is always coming.

I am using snapshot of emulator for launching the emulator in a fast way.Suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important sentence on the [snapshot introduction site](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots):

> This isn't as fully tested as we'd like, but is working usefully for us so we thought it reliable enough to share.

This might be a bug in the snapshot feature.

Why do you use the snapshot anyway? Just for faster booting? As you don't need to restart the emulator to install a new version of your app, I can't see a real benefit of using snapshots. Especially when the feature is not fully tested.

Comment: I am using snapshot for fast booting and also i need to save certain contact details in emulator (as my application requires it). so if i am using snap shot i do not have to enter this contact details each and every time. Anyways i guess you are right. It is a bug. Other features are working properly, but not this sound.

Comment: You don't need the snapshot feature to keep the contacts stored. There is a wipe data feature that is off by default, so your data will be stored in the emulator like in a normal phone...